# Building Complex Dynamic Queries With Django

Tags: python, django

Here is a sample model I have:

```
class Commission(models.Model):
  status                     = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
  customer_name              = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
  order_dat                  = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
```

For status, I can have up to 10 different status types, such as: requested, confirmed, paid...

If I want to build a way to dynamically filter all orders with a specific status with a specific customer, I would do the following:

```
sample_kwargs['status'] = 'active'
sample_kwargs['custom_name'] = 'John Doe'
```

Then get my results with the following:

```
all_commmissions = Commission.objects.filter(**sample_kwargs)
```

This all works well, but what I am now trying to do is is get all the customer's orders that are equal to multiple statuses. For example, I want all of John Doe's orders that are equal to both confirmed, and paid.

Normally I'd used the Q filter

```
  all_commmissions = Commission.objects.filter(
                     Q(status='confirmed') |
                     Q(status='paid'))
```

But this only allows me to hard code things in. How can I build a complex dynamic query (such as my sample_kwargs example) that uses OR? Or what is the best way I can achieve this? I could not find anything in the documentation. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change your status filter params to a list:

```
sample_kwargs['status__in'] = ['confirmed', 'paid']
sample_kwargs['custom_name'] = 'John Doe'
all_commmissions = Commission.objects.filter(**sample_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__in` filter to return results that have a status in any of the values. `setdefault` can be used to create and append to a list of values dynamically

```
 sample_kwargs.setdefault('status__in', []).append('confirmed')
 sample_kwargs.setdefault('status__in', []).append('paid')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
Commission.objects.filter(status='active', custom_name='John Doe')
```

this is basically a shortcut for

```
Commission.objects.filter(Q(status='active') & Q(custom_name='John Doe'))
```

Now, if you want to get `Comission`s with `status` either "paid" or "confirmed" and with `custom_name` "John Doe" via Q objects, you can do

```
Commission.objects.filter(
    (Q(status='active') | Q(status='confirmed')) & Q(custom_name='John Doe'))
```

However, [as Neeraj showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67152228/4360315), in your particular case you don't need to use Q objects and can simply use '__in' lookup for multiple statuses.